# Как включить отображение варнингов в окне проекта?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь перейти с Эклипса на Идею, много чего уже настроил под себя, но один момент очень напрягает. Эклипс в инспекторе показывает статус классов - "с ошибками", "с варнингами" и т.д.:

[image]

А где это включить в Идее, не могу найти, она просто показывает тип элемента:

[image]

Можно ли как-то настроить эти значки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно включить отображение ошибок компиляции. Для этого поставьте галочку в настройках:

*Settings > Compiler > Make project automatically*

Отображение предупреждений в дереве проекта не поддерживается.

Тж. см. [How to see imediately compile errors in project tree of IntelliJ Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502517/how-to-see-imediately-compile-errors-in-project-tree-of-intellij-idea)